# Micronaut mock dependency for tests through constructor that has a service call

Tags: java, junit, constructor, micronaut

I have a class called ServiceA. ServiceA has ServiceB's dependency injected.

ServiceB's constructor initializes a client (say ClientC) used to make a few network calls. The initialization of ClientC does a network call for a health check.

The client has code for connection pooling and handles all the complexity of the system. The whole scenario is represented through the code below:

```
class ClientC{
    
    public static Pool initialize(){
        // makes network call for health check and craetes connection pool.
    }
}

@Singleton
class ServiceB{

    private Pool pool;

    public ServiceB(){
        // network calls made here in constructor.
        pool = ClientC.initialize();
    }

    public Pool getPool(){
        return pool;
    }       
}

@Singleton
class ServiceA{

    @Inject
    private ServiceB serviceB;

    public String someFunction(){
        serviceB.getPool().doSomething();
    }       
}

@MicronautTest
public class ServiceATest{
    
    @Inject
    private ServiceA serviceA;

    @Test
    public void testSomeFucntion(){
        // Fails because no network call can be made in tests. 
    }   

    @MockBean(ServiceB.class)
    ServiceB serviceB(){
        mockBean(ServiceB.class);
    }   
}
```

Now I want to write a test for ServiceA, which has a mock dependency for ServiceB. But, since ServiceB's constructor is doing a health check for the ClientC, my tests are failing. Also, I do not want the tests to be dependent on availability of an external service.
How do I mock the dependency for ServiceB?